# setting padding depending on number of child elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a `DIV` element which may contain 1 or `2 Child DIVs`

Is there a way to say of there is `1 Child element` then the padding should be `15px` otherwise `5px`

It may like

```
<div class="container">
   <div><strike>7.00</strike></div>
   <div>5.00</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="container">
   <div>7.00</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can change the propieties of the child if there is only one with `:only-child ` pseudo-class. If you want change `.container` you can`t with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a trick using margin in the children to get the same effect:

```css
.container div:only-child {
  margin: 15px;
}

div {
  border: solid 1px red;
}

div div {
  margin: 0 5px;
  border-color: green;
  background: #ccc;
}

div div:first-child {
  margin-top: 5px
}

div div:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><del>7.00</del></div>
  <div>5.00</div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div>7.00</div>
</div>
```

**PS** Use `del` tag instead `strike` that is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

**No, there is not.**

CSS does have some complex [**quantity queries**](http://quantityqueries.com/) but these will only style the *children* based on their number.

It is not (currently) possible to style the *parent* based on the number of children as there is no [**Parent Selector**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0):

Based on how old this original thread is I'm not providing exact solutions, however, CSS Tricks put a great article together covering Logical CSS styling. You can [find the article here](https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-logical-styling-based-on-the-number-of-given-elements/).